# Convertigo Http Connector multipart/form-data

Tags: upload, convertigo

How Configurations for Http Connector - Http Transaction for multipart/form-data?
this is my screen shoot setting,

[screen shoot](http://imageshack.com/a/img661/3100/uCiw2W.png)

with this setting, the request was send but the file disappeared from request. anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multi-part form encoded is supported out of the box by Convertigo, except it is supported on the HTML connector and not the HTTP connector so to upload a file :

Create a HTML connector. The hostname, port and isHttps properties are not mandatory to be modified here

Create a HTML transaction, name it "DoUpload"

On this Transaction create a "TransactionStarted" handler (RightClick->new>Handler->Start of Transaction

In this handler create a HTTP-Upload statement (RightClick->new->statement->HTTP_upload_request)

Configure statement properties :
- FilePath to the file to upload (JS property)
- filename to the name of the uploaded file (JSproperty)
- host, port, isHttps to the correct setting for HTTP or https
- URI to the uri path (JS property)

Be sure to set the transaction's "Maintain Connector State" property to "true"

See : http://help.convertigo.com/7.2.1/topic/com.twinsoft.convertigo.studio.help/help/helpRefManual/HTTPuploadrequest.html

This should do the trick.